# How to fit background image to parent element?

Tags: css

I'm struggling to fit the background image to the parent div if the screen size getting wider.
If screen size for mobile, the result is correct what I expect. But if the screen size getting wider the background image will cut off by the parent element.
[image: for mobile screen is correct]

While for desktop screen, the background image will cut off by parent element:
[image: desktop screen]

So far my code like this:

**index.html**

```
<div id="hero">
    <div className="weekend">
      <h1 className="text-center">WEEKEND FROM HOME</h1>
      <h6 className="text-center">Stay active with a little workout.</h6>
    </div>
    <div className="position-relative text-center d-flex justify-content-center">
      <img src={robot} alt="" />
      <button className="btn btn-light lets-go text-center">
        Let's Go
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**style.css**

```
#hero {
   background-image: url("../../assets/shapes/bg-1.svg");
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-color: var(--pinky-50);
   padding-top: 134px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   padding-left: 24px;
   padding-right: 23px;
}
```

So far my solution is adjust padding and height for different screen size but it's not best practice, because sometime i missed for several screen size.

- info: resolution of background image is 1366px x 732px

Comment: Try background-size: contain

Comment: I had the same problem and got it under control with adding aspect-ratio media query (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio). Something like @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) { #hero { background-size: auto 100% } ) should help.

Comment: can you give us the link to you webapp?

Comment: @Gildas.Tambo It's still in the localhost